# Is there a way to save responses to browser's HTTP requests as they happen?

Tags: google-chrome, network-programming, httprequest, har

For example, I know I can use Chrome's "Export HAR..." feature, but if I had the page open for an hour or so, "Export HAR" only saves the contents of the more recent requests, where the archive files representing earlier requests are actually empty. Maybe it depends on the size of the responses, but my archive ended up being 130MB in size and that definitely wasn't all of it.

Answer (score 0):

*** Disclaimer: HttpWatch is a commercial tool and this was posted by its creator Neumetrix Limited ***

With [HttpWatch](https://www.httpwatch.com) you can automatically record and save to HAR files at regular intervals from Chrome:

https://help.httpwatch.com/automatic_recording.html

You can also use the HttpWatch log file format (HWL) resulting in much smaller log files and then export to HAR files at a later time.

Comment: Seems pricey for the basic stuff I need to do. I think I can just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-har